# Grails 3 loading correct resources for an Integration test

Tags: grails-3.0, integration-testing

When my grails app starts in normal development or prod mode it looks for a folder in the src/main/resources folder like so:

File topLevel = grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI('classpath:/courseGuides').file

Whats the proper way to get it to load from src/test/resources when I want to run an integration test for example ?